# Is it practical to use #ifdef's to compile a library without certain features?

Tags: c

So I'm currently working with a proprietary programming language that is C-like. So while this question wasn't directly inspired by a C program, I think those of you who are familiar with C may be able to offer some good insight.

I'm currently working on a library. This library encompasses some basic features as well as features that require other libraries. I'm running into the problem of 'where do I draw the line for how many dependencies are included in this library?'.

So this seems like it could be a fairly common problem. What methods exist for addressing this issue?

Something I've had in mind. Implement #defines and #ifdefs that allow users to compile the library with only the features they want. So essentially, all of the library functions that require additional libraries would be wrapped in #ifdef guards. The user would be responsible for #define'ing the features they want. Essentially, this method would allow a user to still use parts of the library without needing to have other dependent libraries.

Your thoughts? Again, this is for a C-like language. Thus tools like CMake, etc. aren't available.

Comment: Can it be messy? Yes. But it is done quite commonly in C.Two examples: Windows, OpenGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. If you take a look at the Linux kernel for instance, it's done the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and You Should.

I use them whenever i feel the necessity. Also, i have been working on `freeRTOS` and that's how things are being done over there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you go about implementing these in C, how do you let the user control this? Is this something you do with CMake, through compiler flags, etc.?

Comment: The compiler option -D can be used to define the macro MY_MACRO from command line. For example, 

$ gcc -Wall -DMY_MACRO main.c -o main